# cts:search is returning unexpected results for unfiltered search option when wildcard is enabled

Tags: indexing, marklogic, marklogic-7

I am performing **cts:search** with **"unfiltered"** option and wildcard search is enabled (means passing **"wildcarded"**).

In my database, I have inserted 5 xml documents which I have pasted below.

In the below cts:query if the value of **journalTitle** element contains a **wildcard(*)** it's returning me all the 5 documents.

for example: "d*", "di*", "dixi*"

Even if I am passing **"mohi*t"** as a value for **journalTitle** element, I am getting all the five documents in the result.

For **"filtered"** option it is working fine.

I am curious about why this behaviour? and please also let me know how can I correct this for **"unfiltered"** option.

I have searched a lot on google regarding this but did not find the solution.

Please find below the cts:search query and xml files

**cts:query**

```
cts:search(fn:collection(), cts:element-query(
        xs:QName("root"), 
        cts:and-query(
          (
            cts:element-value-query(xs:QName("sourceType"), "JA", ("case-insensitive","diacritic-sensitive","punctuation-sensitive","whitespace-sensitive","wildcarded","lang=en"), 1), 
            cts:element-value-query(xs:QName("journalTitle"), "mohi*t", ("case-insensitive","diacritic-sensitive","punctuation-sensitive","whitespace-sensitive","wildcarded","lang=en"), 1), 
            cts:element-value-query(xs:QName("title"), "title1", ("case-insensitive","diacritic-sensitive","punctuation-sensitive","whitespace-sensitive","wildcarded","lang=en"), 1), 
            cts:element-value-query(xs:QName("volume"), "volume0", ("case-insensitive","diacritic-sensitive","punctuation-sensitive","whitespace-sensitive","wildcarded","lang=en"), 1)
          ), 
          ()
        ), 
        ()
       ),"unfiltered")
```

**XML content - pasted all the five xmls:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <journalTitle>Dinesh</journalTitle>
    <sourceType>JA</sourceType>
    <title>title1</title>
    <volume>volume0</volume>
</root>
-
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <journalTitle>Dixit</journalTitle>
    <sourceType>JA</sourceType>
    <title>title1</title>
    <volume>volume0</volume>
</root>
-
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <journalTitle>Prashant</journalTitle>
    <sourceType>JA</sourceType>
    <title>title1</title>
    <volume>volume0</volume>
</root>
-
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <journalTitle>GAYARI</journalTitle>
    <sourceType>JA</sourceType>
    <title>title1</title>
    <volume>volume0</volume>
</root>
-
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <journalTitle>KEVAL</journalTitle>
    <sourceType>JA</sourceType>
    <title>title1</title>
    <volume>volume0</volume>
</root>
```

You might need the xdmp:plan result so I have pasted it below

**xdmp:plan result:**

```
<qry:query-plan xmlns:qry="http://marklogic.com/cts/query">
    <qry:info-trace>xdmp:eval("xdmp:plan(cts:search(fn:collection(), cts:element-query(&amp;#10;   ...", (), &lt;options xmlns="xdmp:eval"&gt;&lt;database&gt;12874763000056740838&lt;/database&gt;&lt;root&gt;C:\RSuite\modules...&lt;/options&gt;)</qry:info-trace>
    <qry:info-trace>Analyzing path for search: fn:collection()</qry:info-trace>
    <qry:info-trace>Step 1 is searchable: fn:collection()</qry:info-trace>
    <qry:info-trace>Path is fully searchable.</qry:info-trace>
    <qry:info-trace>Gathering constraints.</qry:info-trace>
    <qry:info-trace>Search query contributed 1 constraint: cts:element-query(fn:QName("", "root"), cts:and-query((cts:element-value-query(fn:QName("", "sourceType"), "JA", ("case-insensitive","diacritic-sensitive","punctuation-sensitive","whitespace-sensitive","wildcarded","lang=en"), 1), cts:element-value-query(fn:QName("", "journalTitle"), "mohi*t", ("case-insensitive","diacritic-sensitive","punctuation-sensitive","whitespace-sensitive","wildcarded","lang=en"), 1), cts:element-value-query(fn:QName("", "title"), "title1", ("case-insensitive","diacritic-sensitive","punctuation-sensitive","whitespace-sensitive","wildcarded","lang=en"), 1), cts:element-value-query(fn:QName("", "volume"), "volume0", ("case-insensitive","diacritic-sensitive","punctuation-sensitive","whitespace-sensitive","wildcarded","lang=en"), 1)), ()), ())</qry:info-trace>
    <qry:partial-plan>
        <qry:or-two-queries>
            <qry:element-query>
                <qry:key>10866465315185201428</qry:key>
                <qry:annotation>element(root)</qry:annotation>
                <qry:and-query>
                    <qry:term-query weight="1">
                        <qry:key>15329831187071590131</qry:key>
                        <qry:annotation>element(sourceType,value("JA"))</qry:annotation>
                    </qry:term-query>
                    <qry:term-query weight="0">
                        <qry:key>3029765743981997321</qry:key>
                        <qry:annotation>element(journalTitle)</qry:annotation>
                    </qry:term-query>
                    <qry:term-query weight="1">
                        <qry:key>4206353216190327061</qry:key>
                        <qry:annotation>element(title,value("title1"))</qry:annotation>
                    </qry:term-query>
                    <qry:term-query weight="1">
                        <qry:key>7729558342335907080</qry:key>
                        <qry:annotation>element(volume,value("volume0"))</qry:annotation>
                    </qry:term-query>
                </qry:and-query>
            </qry:element-query>
            <qry:and-two-queries>
                <qry:term-query weight="0">
                    <qry:key>837267169796541076</qry:key>
                    <qry:annotation>link-child(descendant(element(root)))</qry:annotation>
                </qry:term-query>
                <qry:and-query>
                    <qry:term-query weight="1">
                        <qry:key>15329831187071590131</qry:key>
                        <qry:annotation>element(sourceType,value("JA"))</qry:annotation>
                    </qry:term-query>
                    <qry:term-query weight="0">
                        <qry:key>3029765743981997321</qry:key>
                        <qry:annotation>element(journalTitle)</qry:annotation>
                    </qry:term-query>
                    <qry:term-query weight="1">
                        <qry:key>4206353216190327061</qry:key>
                        <qry:annotation>element(title,value("title1"))</qry:annotation>
                    </qry:term-query>
                    <qry:term-query weight="1">
                        <qry:key>7729558342335907080</qry:key>
                        <qry:annotation>element(volume,value("volume0"))</qry:annotation>
                    </qry:term-query>
                </qry:and-query>
            </qry:and-two-queries>
        </qry:or-two-queries>
    </qry:partial-plan>
    <qry:info-trace>Executing search.</qry:info-trace>
    <qry:final-plan>
        <qry:and-query>
            <qry:or-two-queries>
                <qry:element-query>
                    <qry:key>10866465315185201428</qry:key>
                    <qry:annotation>element(root)</qry:annotation>
                    <qry:and-query>
                        <qry:term-query weight="1">
                            <qry:key>15329831187071590131</qry:key>
                            <qry:annotation>element(sourceType,value("JA"))</qry:annotation>
                        </qry:term-query>
                        <qry:term-query weight="0">
                            <qry:key>3029765743981997321</qry:key>
                            <qry:annotation>element(journalTitle)</qry:annotation>
                        </qry:term-query>
                        <qry:term-query weight="1">
                            <qry:key>4206353216190327061</qry:key>
                            <qry:annotation>element(title,value("title1"))</qry:annotation>
                        </qry:term-query>
                        <qry:term-query weight="1">
                            <qry:key>7729558342335907080</qry:key>
                            <qry:annotation>element(volume,value("volume0"))</qry:annotation>
                        </qry:term-query>
                    </qry:and-query>
                </qry:element-query>
                <qry:and-two-queries>
                    <qry:term-query weight="0">
                        <qry:key>837267169796541076</qry:key>
                        <qry:annotation>link-child(descendant(element(root)))</qry:annotation>
                    </qry:term-query>
                    <qry:and-query>
                        <qry:term-query weight="1">
                            <qry:key>15329831187071590131</qry:key>
                            <qry:annotation>element(sourceType,value("JA"))</qry:annotation>
                        </qry:term-query>
                        <qry:term-query weight="0">
                            <qry:key>3029765743981997321</qry:key>
                            <qry:annotation>element(journalTitle)</qry:annotation>
                        </qry:term-query>
                        <qry:term-query weight="1">
                            <qry:key>4206353216190327061</qry:key>
                            <qry:annotation>element(title,value("title1"))</qry:annotation>
                        </qry:term-query>
                        <qry:term-query weight="1">
                            <qry:key>7729558342335907080</qry:key>
                            <qry:annotation>element(volume,value("volume0"))</qry:annotation>
                        </qry:term-query>
                    </qry:and-query>
                </qry:and-two-queries>
            </qry:or-two-queries>
        </qry:and-query>
    </qry:final-plan>
    <qry:info-trace>Selected 5 fragments</qry:info-trace>
    <qry:result estimate="5"/>
</qry:query-plan>
```

Apology if there is any gramatical error.

If you need more info please let me know.

Answer (score 3):

Wildcard searches rely on either the appropriate index, or filtering. Did you check you have enabled `fast element trailing wildcard searches`, and maybe also `trailing wildcard searches` on your database? That will work for patterns with at least 4 starting characters. For three starting characters, you also need to enable `fast element character searches`, and maybe also the `three character searches`.

MarkLogic also allows accurate unfiltered wildcard searches for patterns that start with just two or one character. One way is to enable the `two character searches` and `one character searches` options, but according to the documentation, you don't need to if you enable the three character one in combination with a word lexicon:

> two character searches specifies whether indexes should be created to
>   enable wildcard searches where the search pattern contains two
>   consecutive non-wildcard character (for example, ab*). This index is
>   not needed if you have three character searches and a word lexicon.
>
> one character searches specifies whether indexes should be created to
>   enable wildcard searches where the search pattern contains a single
>   non-wildcard character (for example, a*). This index is not needed if
>   you have three character searches and a word lexicon.

*(source: Admin UI Help tab)*

Thnx to Dave for pointing to [Understanding the Wildcard Indexes](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/wildcard#id_61884) in which all is explained in further detail.

HTH!

Comment: There are index settings to allow one- or two-character wildcard searches. However, it takes somewhat large indexes to support this, so customers are encouraged to consider whether they might be happy with three-character. You can read more in [Understanding the Wildcard Indexes](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/wildcard#id_61884).

Answer (score 3):

It is a better idea to enable a word lexicon with a codepoint collation in conjunction with the three character wildcards. The one and two character indexes are very very expensive.